# Printing the value field in python if the key matches with today's date

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to print the name of the birthday boy. For that, I have written the following code :

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
a = now.strftime("%d-%B")

birthdays = {
              '1-December': 'ALICE',
              '19-December': 'BOB',
              '20-May': 'MORRIS'
            }
```

The variable `a` in the code stores today's date and month. If the key in my dictionary matches with today's date and month, I want to print it's corresponding value, i.e., the name of the birthday boy.

How could I do this?

Comment: Curious as what you did try? Mind to show ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a `.get` call on the dictionary to check for any birthdays.:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today = now.strftime("%d-%B")
>>> birthdays = {
...         '01-December': 'ALICE',
...         '19-December': 'BOB',
...         '20-May': 'MORRIS',
...         '09-December': 'PRUDHVI'
...         }
>>> birthday_today = birthdays.get(today)
>>> if birthday_today: print "Happy birthday %s!" % birthday_today
... else: print "No birthday today"
... 
Happy birthday PRUDHVI!
```

Note that there are 2 issues with your current approach

1. You are saving birthdays as `1-December`, but the date strings are of the form `01-December` with your `strftime` logic
2. There might be multiple boys having a bithday on same date, which the current dictionary will not be able to store. Use lists instead of string to save the names in the dictionary, something like: `birthdays = {'09-December': ['ALICE', 'BOB'], '20-May': ['MORRIS']}`

Comment: You are spot on!!! I have two guys who have birthdays on the same day. I have tried and it is printing only one name. How could I print both their names?

Comment: @prudhvi Use lists instead of string to save the names in the dictionary, something like: `birthdays = {'09-December': ['ALICE', 'BOB'], '20-May': ['MORRIS']}`

Comment: @prudhvi Happy to help, don't forget to [accept and upvote the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if that worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Two steps. 
1) check if key a is in birthdays
2) print it.

```
if a in birthdays:
    print(birthdays[a])
```

EDIT:

or even simpler as suggested by Avihoo Mamka.

```
birthdays.get(a, 'No birthday found for this date')
```

Comment: Why not `birthdays.get(a, 'No birthday found for this date')` ?

Comment: guess that's even simpler.